# Need more than 0 values to unpack (python coords on a variable error using tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an space invaders clone using tkinter...

Ther thing is that I am having an error that says ValueError: Need more than 0 values to unpack on a variable assignment (keep reading please) when my "shot" is deleted because of it reaching the canvas limit in order to stop the "shot" going over and over beyond the visible area of the canvas...

The code I am posting here is just a lil piece of the whole game code I have so far, but it is exactly the same code I am using for the "Shot" behavior on the actual project...

I am aware that the code is working, and the "Shot" do dissapear, In other words... It is working, but I keep getting this error on the shell, And when I use this function side by side with other 9 functions (The ones that make the invaders shoot) The program starts getting laggy and buggy, and after a few seconds it stops working...

So I am kind of suspicious that the thing that is breaking my program is that error and dont really know what to do.

Hope you can Help me out here. Thank You!

PD: Excuse my awful eng skills.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

def LoadImage(name):
    rute = os.path.join('Imagenes',name)
    image = PhotoImage(file=rute)
    return image

root=Tk()

DxShot= 0 #Globals of Directions on x and y
DyShot= -3

def PlayWindow():
    root.withdraw()
    VentanaPlay= Toplevel()
    VentanaPlay.title("Kill'em all!'")
    VentanaPlay.resizable(width=NO, height=NO)
    VentanaPlay.geometry("540x540")

    def Shot():
        x,y= CanvPlay.coords(Ship) #This reads the place from where the shot will have to be created
        ShotImage=LoadImage("Shot.gif")
        Shot1=CanvPlay.create_image(x, y-22, image=ShotImage)
        CanvPlay.img=ShotImage
        def ShotMove():
            global DxShot, DyShot
            x1,y1= CanvPlay.coords(Shot1) #here's where I'm getting the error...
            if y1+DyShot<=0:
                CanvPlay.delete(Shot1) #Also, if I use destroy instead of delete it says "destroy() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"
                print("Shot deleted")
            CanvPlay.coords(Shot1, x1+DxShot, y1+DyShot)
            CanvPlay.after(3,ShotMove)
        ShotMove()
        VentanaPlay.after(0,ShotMove)

    def Fire(event):
        Shot()

    CanvPlay= Canvas(VentanaPlay, width=540, height=540, bg="white")
    CanvPlay.config(cursor="dotbox")
    CanvPlay.place(x=-1,y=-1)
    CanvPlay.bind("<space>", Fire)
    CanvPlay.focus_set()

    ShipImage= LoadImage("Ship.gif")
    Ship= CanvPlay.create_image(260, 520, image=ShipImage)

    VentanaPlay.mainloop()

Buttun= Button(root, text= "click me", command=PlayWindow)
Buttun.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the full traceback error I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 531, in callit
func(*args)
File "C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/crap shot", line 28, in ShotMove
x1,y1= CanvPlay.coords(Shot1)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 531, in callit
func(*args)
File "C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/crap shot", line 28, in ShotMove
x1,y1= CanvPlay.coords(Shot1)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is that `CanvPlay.coords(Shot1)` is returning an empty list or None, and your code isn't prepared to handle that case. This can happen if, for example, you delete the item for which you are trying to get the coordinates.

In fact, your `ShotMove` function has code that deletes the shot, and then it goes on to try to move the shot again. If you delete the shot, you probably don't want to use `after` to move the shot again. Perhaps the simple solution is to change your ShotMove function to look like this:

```
def ShotMove():
    global DxShot, DyShot
    x1,y1= CanvPlay.coords(Shot1) #here's where I'm getting the error...
    if y1+DyShot<=0:
        CanvPlay.delete(Shot1) 
        print("Shot deleted")
    else:
        CanvPlay.coords(Shot1, x1+DxShot, y1+DyShot)
        CanvPlay.after(3,ShotMove)
```

You have another problem in your code, in that you call `mainloop` more than once. Generally speaking, you should only ever call `mainloop` exactly once. This might be part of the reason why your program gets laggy and buggy after a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah Thank You! I notice that after I post the question, and btw! I use mainloop's on every new window because if I dont, some images would not be displayed... I dont really know why... But that's how i managed to fix it.. Anyways, Do you think that may be the cause of the random closes and Bugs I am getting?

Comment: Your assessment that multiple calls to mainloop is the fix for images not showing up is false. Yes, that could easily be your problem. You need to have a single instance of `Tk` and a single call to `mainloop`. Anything else will give unexpected behavior.

Comment: Ok! I already solve a few image related problems, so Im  gonna try removing those mainloops... Although, Even with all those mainloops, when the program runs (In the right way, I mean, with everything working) It doesnt seem to matter. But thank you for your explanation!

As I said, im gonna try removing them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store a list of Shots (Shot1s) somehow, the way you are using a nested function won't work.

Nested functions can have confusing results, because Python does not evaluate every variable in the function and store it when it is defined, they are accessed on use. So when you first call the ShotMove() inside Shot(), the interpreter looks for something called Shot1 which it finds. However when you attempt to pass the ShotMove function outside the Shot function and call it there, the interpreter cannot find any Shot1 (it no longer exists). I assume the strange error (instead of a NameError or something) might be because python might check for NameErrors when the function is initially defined and not on every run.

Comment: I have already notice where the error is... When I delete the image, (As the full function is recursive) "Shot1" Is no longer an object on the canvas, in other words, it no longer exists, so when I call the x,y= CanvPlay.cords(Shot1) The argument that is entering there is'nt really nothing, because of the wipe that I made to the Shot1 when it reaches the top.

Anyway! Thanks! :)